# iOS: MDM Check-in samples

Tags: ios, mdm, payload

I am in early stage of Mobile Device Management implementation. I am in process to get iOS Enterprise developer account.I have already started exploring MDM Server implementation.

I need some iOS sample Check-in data which is received from iOS device. These samples are required to understand to write APIs in server side,because these APIs should be common for Blackberry,Android and other mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get step by step all the sample plist in the [MDM_Protocol](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) document also.
For example in device check-in process when iOS device receives the push notification from MDM server via APNS then device can respond to MDM Sever as below sample plist format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict>
    <key>Status</key> 
    <string>Idle</string> 
    <key>UDID</key> 
    <string> [ redacted ] </string>
</dict> 
</plist>
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have an Apple Developer account, log in and go to iOS Provisioning Portal->Certificates->Other and look for the link to the document "Mobile Device Management Protocol Reference". This document explains the structure of a device check-in.

UPDATE (30-Sep-2012): It appears the link text has changed from "Mobile Device Management Protocol Reference" to "Configuration Profile Reference".