# How to check whether device is enrolled in MDM

Tags: ios, mdm, iphone-privateapi

I am looking for an API which will allow me to check whether MDM profile is installed on a device.

It won't be submitted to AppStore, so private API are fine with me. However, it should work on jailed phone (so jailbreak solutions aren't applicable).

**Update 1**

I am looking for a way to determine on iOS device whether this device is enrolled (vs checking from MDM server what devices are enrolled).

Comment: For people who marks it as non constructive. Please, leave a comment behind, what exactly is non constructive in this question.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039236/ios-mdm-check-in-samples

Comment: @sangony: Thanks. I know about checkin. However, I need to determine on mobile device whether this device is enrolled or not (I wrote an update to the question)

Comment: Have a look at the 2013 WWDC session 301.  I can't say what's in it due to the NDA, but I think that one of the features they describe might help.

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: you say you want to detect from app - but did you manage to detect from server side if a request that comes from an app is from an enrolled device? how?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I can think of is installing the application through the MDM server (using the `ChangeManagementState` option to take control of an already install application). This will allow you to set managed app configuration options on the MDM server which the application can read from `UserDefaults`.

You can see how to do this here: https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf#b3

If you need to verify that the correct MDM server is managing the device and not some random MDM server, you can create some type of signed document that is unique to the device (include the UDID) and signed by a private key unique to the server. The app can then verify this signature with the public key (probably shipped in the app binary since this seems to be a private thing) and determine if the app and device are managed.

The easiest option would probably be something like JSON Web Tokens. There are other options that exist as well: pkcs7, SMIME, CMS, etc.

For example, in the body of the JWT token, you could include the server domain, and the device UDID. This way the device can verify that this signed token is intended for this device and not simply being copied and reused from another legitimately managed device. You could also include a timestamp (and/or expiration) value to require that the token be reissued by the MDM server over some set time interval to ensure that it's recent.

```
{
  "sub": "SOME-DEVICE-UDID",
  "iat": 1516239022,
  "iss": "mdm.example.com"
}
```

There are many ways to do this, I am just most familiar with JWT tokens. There are existing JWT libraries for Swift and Objective-C which could be used within your app to verify this token. Then you could be reasonably sure that the device is managed and managed by the intended server.